# How to tell a program to run in user mode instead of administrator'

Tags: windows-vista

I have build a simple win32, 32 bits software that:

- is really simple: one windows, two buttons,
- does not need any external exotic library (the ideal is to run under any Windows computer).

This program works fine on xp and 7, but on Vista, the program requires to be running in administrator mode.

How can I tell Vista to run this program "normally"? I tried to edit properties, but nothing things strange. I don't know what requires the program to be launched as admin.

Comment: The most likely cause is Windows heuristics.   That is, Windows thinks your program looks like the sort of program that will need admin privileges.  The resolution is to include a manifest that explicitly says that you don't, e.g., using the `/MANIFESTUAC` linker option.

Comment: Crystal ball says that Vista thinks your program might be an installer.  It cannot know this, it has to guess.  A program name like update.exe or setup.exe will do it.

Comment: @HansPassant Hum nice idea, indeed, the program is named something_updater.exe. Next try on monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Vista, this problem comes from the executable name: `something_updater.exe`.

Some solutions exist to correct the problem, choose one:

1. With a manifest file:

   Add in the program folder some `something_updater.exe.manifest` file containing:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
       <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
       <assemblyIdentity
           version="1.0.0.0"
           name="something_updater.exe"
           type="win32"
       />
       <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
           <security>
               <requestedPrivileges>
                   <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
               </requestedPrivileges>
           </security>
       </trustInfo>
       </assembly>
   ```
2. At link time:

   Add the following option to linker when building the executable:

   ```
   /MANIFESTUAC:level=asInvoker /MANIFESTUAC:uiAccess=false
   ```
3. Change the program name, with some name not containing `update` nor `setup`.